# Is there a way to make this HTML and CSS work on a Teachable page?

Tags: html, css

So I'm having some difficulty with using HTML and CSS on a platform called Teachable.

Basically, I'm trying to make 2 columns:
- Column 1 - image
- Column 2 - Text

When I put  `<div class="column">` only on Column 1 I get this:

[image: Layout 1]

When I put  `<div class="column">` on both parts, I get what you can see here.

[image: Layout 2]

As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case. Would it be possible to make column 1 have around 25% of the width, while column 2 around 75% of the width?

This is the css code I'm using:

```
/* Three image containers (use 25% for four, and 50% for two, etc) */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clear floats after image containers */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: If you could link to the documentation of this "Teachable" framework, that would be helpful. It's not entirely clear what you want the end result to look like. Also, please share the HTML that goes along with the CSS you're using (a [mcve]). You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Heretic Monkey. I tried BlazeGear10's option but I get more or less one of the same results. The only thing that teachable offers seems to be this: https://support.teachable.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*created separate classes for div sections of img and text*/
/*column-1 is img div*/
.column-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/*img must be set to 100% width to fill div container*/
img {
  width: 100%;
}

/*column-2 is text div*/
.column-2 {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 5px;
}
/*Change padding and width to fit your needs.*/
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="column-1">
      <img src="SS_img_01-2-s.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
      <p>
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
        As you can see, column 2 becomes very narrow in this case.
      </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I think you're trying to get to, however, I could be wrong.

Edit:
 Ok, so you could just add 'height: 100%' to column-1, unless you want to include things below the img, but if it's just the img and the text, then it should be okay. If you do need to add things below the img, I think using z-index and positioning the elements in the right way should work. Hopefully this is what you're looking for. Also, for some reason, the code snippet does not show the result I'm getting when I run my code on it so make sure to check that it works yourself.

Comment: Hello BlazeGear10.
Thanks a lot for the help.
I think we're close to solving this but there's still a small issue, because the text from column 2 goes under column 1.

So here is how it should look (default version) and what we have right now. 

https://imgur.com/W16urRs

Oh, and I also had to make the width for column 2 around 105% in order to get it to be like the "Default" version.

Comment: Even though it looks much better now with the variables that you've given me, truth is that it's still not dividing the 2 columns, even with the height included - that does seem very strange.